# Validação multi formulários Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, ajax

Montei um formulário, onde possuo um SELECT com três opções e ao selecioná-las, o jquery exibe opções de formulário diferentes, com seus respectivos conteúdos (são três DIVs com classe "hide" para ocultá-los). O problema que ao submeter o formulário, os campos "required" dos outros inputs interferem no processamento. Alguém poderia me ajudar a chegar em uma solução eficaz, sem necessidade de gambiarra e mantendo a necessidade de validação pelo lado cliente, mesmo com javascript desabilitado?

Seguem os códigos:

```js
$(function() {
 // Formulários
 $("#form").change(function() {
  var $this, secao, atual, campos, input;

  campos = $("div[data-name]");
  campos.addClass("hide");

  if(this.value !== "") {
   secao = $('option[data-section][value="' + this.value + '"]', this).attr("data-section");
   atual = campos.filter("[data-name=" + secao + "]");

   if(atual.length !== 0) {
    atual.removeClass("hide");
   }
  }
 });


 var formID = '#' + $('form').data('form-id');

 $(formID).submit(function() {
  var dados = $(this).serialize();

  $('#mensagem')
   .fadeIn('slow')
   .css('display', 'block')
   .addClass('alert alert-light')
   .html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw'></i> Enviando...");
  $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : '../../mail.php',
   data : dados,
   dataType: 'json',
   success :  function(response) {
    $('#mensagem')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .removeClass()
    .addClass(response.tipo)
    .html('')
    .html('' + response.mensagem + '');
   }
  });
  $(this).trigger('reset');
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#mensagem").fadeOut('slow'); }, 10000)
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="formSelect" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i>*</i> Formulário</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="formSelect" id="formSelect" required>
    <option>-- Selecione --</option>
    <option data-section="form1" value="form1">Formulário 1</option>
    <option data-section="form2" value="form2">Formulário 2</option>
    <option data-section="form3" value="form3">Formulário 3</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <div data-name="form1" class="hide">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="campo1" class="col-form-label"><i>*</i> Campo 1</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo1" id="campo1" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="formMSG" class="col-form-label">Mensagem</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="formMSG" id="formMSG"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-name="form2" class="hide">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="campo2" class="col-form-label"><i>*</i> Campo 1</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo2" id="campo2" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="formMSG" class="col-form-label">Mensagem</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="formMSG" id="formMSG"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-name="form3" class="hide">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="campo3" class="col-form-label"><i>*</i> Campo 1</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo3" id="campo3" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="formMSG" class="col-form-label">Mensagem</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="formMSG" id="formMSG"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div id="mensagem" class="" role="alert"></div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Da forma que quer fazer, tem que criar um formulário pra cada coisa.

Comment: Opa @Sam tudo certo? Então, teoricamente eu "tenho um formulário para cada um", porém, estão no mesmo código. O problema é que preciso que fiquem na mesma página. Tem ideia de como posso fazer? Gerar o conteúdo por Jquery seria um meio correto?

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo está tudo dentro do mesmo `form`.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, mas entendi, você diz, colocar form completo para cada conteúdo, correto?

Comment: É, separar cada segmento com uma tag `<form></form>`, assim vc consegue controlar as coisas de forma separada. Ao submeter um, o outro não influirá.

Comment: @Sam separei os formulários com a tag form, porém, ele não envia mais o formulário (nenhum dos três). Já tentei debugar também e não encontro erro, é como se o "submit" não funcionasse, ele simplesmente recarrega a página